# What's the expression for the root variable in swf file?

Tags: flash, url

I know nothing about flash. I only need to change a few variables in a swf file. the swf file uses `../` for root directory, so, when I play this swf from other places than its designed directory, it will query wrong URL.

I can change to http://domain.com/ but it's better I can use a proper expression for this. What's that expression? Thanks!

Edit: the swf are in this directory:

```
root/domain/content/swf
```

the swf file has some ../url to query files under the content directory

```
root/domain/content/stuffs/items/files
```

If I play the swf in another directory, for example, `root/domain/topics/stories/jokes/`
then, the swf will query `root/domain/topics/stories/jokes/files`, this is wrong. So I want to use a fixed expression to replace `../`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, but if it is about URL to the root of a web server, you can use `/` instead of the current `../`. So URLs would for example be like "/myproject/myfile.xml", if myproject is a directory directly under the root of the web server (this goes for URLs in general and is not Flash specific, URLs work the same way in Flash/ActionScript as elsewhere).

**Edit**: OK, after reading your edit of the question, I still would recommend using URLs with the  full path from the root (getting to the root using an initial /), like `/domain/content/` for the content directory, and URLs like `/somefile.xml` for files directly under the root.